# Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1 issue

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, grub2, windows-8, bootloader

I have installed window 8.1 after cleaning my hard disk..and then installed ubuntu 14.04 with the help of ubuntu forum directions..

But after installing both, window 8.1 sometimes start and sometimes not. Even if this starts it automatically restarts after sometime.

My system does not support UEFI.

Grub is showing both ubuntu and windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would verify that the disk is good first as disk sectors going bad could cause the Windows to fail intermittently. Also, I would check that all RAM is good -- same reason. A bad spot in high RAM could crash the Windows but only when enough Windows are open that high RAM gets used.

Then I would boot the Windows install, delete all partitions, let Windows create a partition from the first half of the disk (leave the rest of the disk for Linux later). Once the Windows is installed, updated, and working, then I would install the Linux on the unused area of the disk. I have done it successfully this way with Windows and Linux for over 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the "Fast Boot" option off in Windows 8.1 (it saves the current state of the system to free space on your hard disk) It is hardly recommend to put it off if you are using a multi boot environment. You find this option under Energy Options -> System Options --> Options for Shutting Down -> Fast Boot activate (recommended) ...just set it off. I hopt I could help ;) ( I have the same set up and it is just working fine)

Comment: Actually  I tried this..but it didn't work out. I have also read about(for such kind of issues) to 'off the secure boot option in BIOS'. But i am not able to find the secure boot option in my BIOS.(It may be due to unavailability of  UEFI ). Does your system has UEFI? (For the time being I shifted back to window 8 and ubuntu 14.04 ...that is working fine till now. But i am still searching for the reason of this bug and its solution ... as I want to shift to window 8.1+ubuntu 14.04)